# webpack plugin - problems in watch mode

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin, webpack-watch

**TL;DR**

I want to pre-compile a bunch of *.tpl files to a templates.js file that can be required and used in main.js. I also want webpack in watch mode to catch changes in the .tpl files.

**Longer description**

The plugin pseudo code is something like this:

```
function Tmpl(options) {}

Tmpl.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {
    compiler.plugin('compilation', (compilation) =>  {
        // Get template files and bundle them all to one file
        var code = getFilesAndBundleStuff();

        // Write the output to a file to be required in main.js
        fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'templates.js'), code);
    });
};

module.exports = Tmpl;
```

That last part that writes the result to a new file, triggers a bunch of watch events and things goes kind of bananas. I'm not sure "compilation" is the right place in the chain to do this job, but I'm new to webpack and don't get how that chain really works.

The whole thing works fine in normal webpack mode, but it would be awesome to get it working in --watch mode.

Comment: I wrote a loader instead. It doesn't solve the "I want each template in a seperate file" problem, but it works with one file containing them all. Still that compiler plugin chain is a bit of a mystery.. https://gist.github.com/fractalf/0be95add0b31b1448ee8c4df8204f601

Comment: Also I'm not sure watch mode in webpack will work on files that are not directly imported/required somewhere in the source